# Minimum Variance Unbiased Estimator for a Negative Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation, negative-binomial

Given a negative binomial distribution parameterized by an unknown mean $\mu$ and known dispersion parameter $\alpha$ (so that the total variance is of the form $\mu + \alpha*\mu^2$), what is the minimum variance unbiased estimator for the mean $\mu$?  And does this estimator obtain the Cramer-Rao lower bound?